# Error: Expected an object as the target scope

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

2 days ago, my web-extensions program have no problem.

But today, same program make below error.

=====

Error: Expected an object as the target scope

Schemas.jsm:2641:15

> let obj = Cu.createObjectIn(context.cloneScope);

=====

enviroment:
Firefox Developer Edition
60.0b2(64bit)

=====

This is java script for popup.

The point that the error is occur is below:

> chrome.extension;

chrome; < no error

chrome.extension; < error

Comment: No error on Firefox Quantum 58.0.2(64bit). Both tried on debugging mode.

Answer (score 1):

It is changed not to be able to access chrome.extension
on a window.unload event in a popup.

Now, I've resolved this error.

```
// error
window.unload = function() {
    var ex = chrome.extension; //error : Expected an object as the target scope
}

// fixed
function access_extention() {
    var ex = chrome.extension; 
}

window.onblur = access_extention;
window.onbeforeunload = access_extention;
```